# How can I display elements into each row?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

currently I am trying to display countries into a Material-UI table. However, all the data is displaying into one row. Anyone know how to fix it? The country array contains elements per index.

```
<TableCell component="th" id={labelId} scope="row" >
   {country}
</TableCell>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<Table >
   <TableBody>
      {generateRows()}
   </TableBody>
</Table>
```

```
const countries =['india','usa']
const generateRows = (countries)=>{
     return countries.map(country=>{
          return (
           <TableRow>
              <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                  {country}
              </TableCell>
           </TableRow >
          )
    })

}
```